# Getting the thumbnail URL from getChildrenCategories()

Tags: magento

I've been driving myself crazy trying to display thumbnail images for a list of sub categories I'm attempting to display in a footer. I've tried the solution found here: http://www.douglasradburn.co.uk/getting-category-thumbnail-images-with-magento/ but no luck!

Here is the code I am using at the moment. Everything works fine apart from the img src renders empty:

```
        <? $artisans = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(9)->getChildrenCategories(); ?>
    <ul class="artists">
    <? $i = 0; foreach($artisans as $artisan):
    ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?= $artisan->getUrl() ?>" title="<?= $artisan->getName() ?>"><img src="<?= $artisan->getThumbnailUrl() ?>" /></a>
        </li>
    <? if(++$i > 7) break; endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

SOLUTION (thanks Lucasmus!):

```
    <? $artisans = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(9)->getChildrenCategories(); ?>
    <ul class="artists">
    <? $i = 0; foreach($artisans as $artisan): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?= $artisan->getUrl() ?>" title="<?= $artisan->getName() ?>"><img src="<?= Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$artisan->load($artisan->getId())->getThumbnail() ?>" width="96" height="96" /></a>
        </li>
    <? if(++$i > 7) break; endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a good chance that there is not enough information loaded from the childcategory. It could help if you added `$artisan->load($artisan->getId());` before getting the actual variables from the `$artisan`.

Comment: Thanks so much. Apparently I can't vote up yet as I haven't got any reputation but I really appreciate your help!

Comment: You can accept the answer maybe? :-) No problem, good that it works!

Answer (score 0):

If you try `$artisan->getThumbnail()` instead of `$artisan->getThumbnailUrl()`? I think that is the correct attribute name.

Comment: Thanks Lucasmus - I should have explained that I had tried that first but it did not work. Originally I had used getChildren() but could not find a way to sort by position. After some searching found that getChildrenCategories() did this as default but now I cannot find a way to get the thumbnail url.

Answer (score 0):

yeah but the $artisan->getThumbnailUrl() calls $artisan->getThumbnail()
so why dont you in you script first set a thumbnail value you know exists for the getthumbnail() to call. 
then you'll know it's a db naming problem

Comment: Hi Gerard, thanks for your response! I have tried that and so I assume there is something wrong with calling GetThumbnail() from a category called with getChildrenCategories().